# Can you further speed up pd.DataFrame.agg()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas.DataFrame with 387 rows and 26 columns. This DataFrame is then Groupby()-ed and agg()-ed, turning into a DataFrame with 1 row and 111 columns. This takes about 0.05s. For example:

```
frames = frames.groupby(['id']).agg({"bytes": ["count",
                                                        "sum",
                                                        "median",
                                                        "std",
                                                        "sum",
                                                        "min",
                                                        "max"],
                         # === add about 70 more lines of this ===
                                     "pixels": "sum"}
```

All of these use Pandas' built-in Cython functions, e.g. sum, std, min, max, first, etc. I am looking to speed this process up, but is there even a way to do such a thing? Seems like it is already considered 'vectorized' to my understanding. Thus, there isn't anything more to do with Cython is there?

Maybe calculating each column separately without the .agg() would be faster?

Would greatly appreciate any ideas, or confirmation that there is nothing else to be done. Thanks!

Edit!

Here's a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

aggs = ["sum", "mean", "std", "min"]
cols = {k:aggs for k in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'}

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(387, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
df['id'] = 1
print(df.groupby("id").agg(cols))
```

cProfile results:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('df.groupby("id").agg(cols)', sort='cumtime')
```

```
         79825 function calls (78664 primitive calls) in 0.076 seconds



   Ordered by: cumulative time



   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

        1    0.000    0.000    0.076    0.076 {built-in method builtins.exec}

        1    0.000    0.000    0.076    0.076 <string>:1(<module>)

        1    0.000    0.000    0.076    0.076 generic.py:964(aggregate)

        1    0.000    0.000    0.075    0.075 apply.py:143(agg)

        1    0.000    0.000    0.075    0.075 apply.py:405(agg_dict_like)

        1    0.000    0.000    0.062    0.062 apply.py:435(<dictcomp>)

   130/26    0.000    0.000    0.059    0.002 generic.py:225(aggregate)

       26    0.001    0.000    0.058    0.002 generic.py:278(_aggregate_multiple_funcs)

       78    0.001    0.000    0.023    0.000 generic.py:322(_cython_agg_general)

       28    0.000    0.000    0.023    0.001 frame.py:573(__init__)
```

Comment: 0.05 seconds seems pretty fast; certainly below human reaction time. What is your target: do you have thousands of such dataframes to process, or is your actual data(frame) much larger?

Comment: @9769953 The size of the dataframes are accurate, but I do have to process thousands of these similarly sized dataframes. The data comes in at up to maybe 10000 dfs/min, so that's what I'm aiming for, although it might be unrealistic.

Comment: I think you need to parallelize now, the timings seems decent

Comment: As per another comment: I'd just run multiple processes next to each other. Depending on the rest of the script and your machine, I/O may become more of a bottleneck.

Comment: And indeed, at 10000 dfs/min, perhaps Pandas simply isn't the best tool. It's good for quick development and analyses, but for continuous processing of large amounts of data, perhaps other packages (there are numerous, mostly parallel processing, alternatives for Pandas) are better. Or it might even need to be rewritten in another language.

Comment: I fully agree, `pandas` is awesome for the flexibility, but once you have a very specific (and here simple) task to perform, just hardcode the operations without libraries or with a lower level language.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. I am currently running multiple processes which get the data from a Queue, and send them to a function containing similar code for processing. Unfortunately, I am still unable to reach my target.

Comment: As for Pandas alternatives, may I have a few suggestions? Considering I am already running them in multiple processes using multiprocessing, will alternatives that leverage parallelism be "thread-safe"? E.g. modin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some benchmarks (with 10 columns to aggregate and 6 aggregation functions for each column, and at most 100 unique ids). It seems that the total time to run the aggregation does not change until the number of rows is somewhere between 10k and 100k.

If you know your dataframes in advance, you can concatenate them into a single big DataFrame with two-level index, run groupby on two columns and get significant speedup. In a way, this runs the calculation on batches of dataframes.

In my example, it takes around 400ms to process a single DataFrame, and 600ms to process a batch of 100 DataFrames, with an average speedup of around 60x.

Here is the general approach (using 100 columns instead of 10):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_rows = 100
num_cols = 100

# builds a random df
def build_df():
  # build some df with num_rows rows and num_cols cols to aggregate
  df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": np.random.randint(0, 100, num_rows),
  })
  for i in range(num_cols):
    df[i] = np.random.randint(0, 10, num_rows)
  return df

agg_dict = {
    i: ["count", "sum", "median", "std", "min", "max"]
    for i in range(num_cols)
}

# get a single small df
df = build_df()

# build 100 random dataframes
dfs = [build_df() for _ in range(100)]
# set the first df to be equal to the "small" df we computed before
dfs[0] = df.copy()
big_df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(100))

%timeit big_df.groupby([big_df.index.get_level_values(0), "id"]).agg(agg_dict)
# 605 ms per loop, for 100 dataframe
agg_from_big = big_df.groupby([big_df.index.get_level_values(0), "id"]).agg(agg_dict).loc[0]

%timeit df.groupby("id").agg(agg_dict)
# 417 ms per loop, for one dataframe
agg_from_small = df.groupby("id").agg(agg_dict)

assert agg_from_small.equals(agg_from_big)
```

Here is the benchmarking code. The timings are comparable until the number of rows increases to 10k to 100k:

```
def get_setup(n):
  return f"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = {n}
num_cols = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({{
    "id": np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
}})
for i in range(num_cols):
  df[i] = np.random.randint(0, 10, N)

agg_dict = {{
    i: ["count", "sum", "median", "std", "min", "max"]
    for i in range(num_cols)
}}
"""

from timeit import timeit
def time_n(n):
  return timeit(
      "df.groupby('id').agg(agg_dict)", setup=get_setup(n), number=100
  )

times = pd.Series({n: time_n(n) for n in [10, 100, 1000, 10_000, 100_000]})
# 10         4.532458
# 100        4.398949
# 1000       4.426178
# 10000      5.009555
# 100000    11.660783
```

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer. My data comes in at real-time, thus I am not too sure if this solution would be applicable unfortunately. Would it be a bad idea to wait a set time for data to accumulate before sending it off to be processed as a larger df?

Comment: It will depend on whether you need to know the answer to a previous aggregation in order to get the next dataframe. If not, buffering appears to be more efficient. Cool question by the way, I was really surprised by how slow pandas appears here.

Comment: Thanks and thank you for all the help! I will try out buffering tomorrow.